# Fading in Page Content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I have my website which has a div container on the left side which includes my navBar with links. On the right side is another div container which I want content to fade in when a link is clicked. I don't want the whole page to refresh however. I have the code which will do this but it won't work for some reason. It worked on a previous blank html document however. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styless.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../images/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
<link href="../fadeStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../GJDG/js/nav.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../images/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../images/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
            'overlayColor'      : '#000',
            'overlayOpacity'    : 0.9,
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',

            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">' +(title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
        });         
    });
</script>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("img.a").hover(
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");
        },
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
        });

        $("img.c").hover(
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");
        },
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
        });

        $("img.e").hover(
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");
        },
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
        });

        });
    </script>

<style>
body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
.container {
width: 100%; left: 0; right: 0; top:0; bottom: 0; position: fixed; overflow: auto;
background: rgba(16,16,16,0.0);
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div id="menu">
<img style="position:absolute; top:25px; left:50px; width:200px; height:73px" src="../../../Envy1.png">
<div style="position: absolute; top:630px; left:50px; font-size:11px; width:200px; color:#FFF">&copy; 2012 Envy Cosmetics</div>

<div id="navBar">
<font face="abeatbyKai">
<ul id="menu-list"> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="../News.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="one">News</a></li> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="../About Us.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="two">About Us</a></li> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="../Gallery.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="three">Gallery</a></li> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="../Affiliates.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="four">Affiliates</a></li> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="../Biography.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="five">Biography</a></li> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="../Contact.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="six">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</font>
</div>

<div class="fadehover1">
<a href=""><img src="../../../twitter1.png" alt="" class="a" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="../../../twitter2.png" alt="" class="b" /></a>
</div>
<div class="fadehover2">
<a href=""><img src="../../../facebook1.png" alt="" class="c" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="../../../facebook2.png" alt="" class="d" /></a>
</div>
<div class="fadehover3">
<a href=""><img src="../../../youtube1.png" alt="" class="e" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="../../../youtube2.png" alt="" class="f" /></a>
</div>

</div>

<div id="main">

    <div id="gallery1">
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/1_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/1_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/2_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/2_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/3_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/3_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/4_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/4_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/5_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/5_s.jpg" /></a>        
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/6_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/6_s.jpg" /></a><br>
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/7_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/7_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/8_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/8_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/9_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/9_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/10_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/10_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/11_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/11_s.jpg" /></a>
    <a rel="example_group" href="../images/12_b.jpg" title="ENVY!"><img alt="" src="../images/12_s.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
          </div>

         </div>

 <script src="../jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $.backstretch("photo1.jpg", {speed: 500});
</script>
<div id="mesh"></div>
```

nav.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#main').load($().attr('href'));
});


$('.menu_side').click(function() {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#main').hide().load(href).fadeIn('fast');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you mean when you say "it won't work?"  What does it do?  Do you get any JavaScript errors?  Does it do something different than expected?

Comment: Link to the website please. I won't judge.

Comment: What is this `$().attr('href')`?

Comment: I mean when I click a link it just jumps to the linked html file instead of fading into the div I commanded it to. So basically the whole nav.js isn't working.

Comment: ok I'M REALLY NEW to javascript/html so I got this tutorial off of this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmfZp4iFzOs&feature=relmfu
It worked but when I put it into my own website it didn't. And I can't show my website because I don't have a domain yet

Comment: I think people should have to take a test before asking a question; for those that don't pass, it says "read <book on tagged word>"

Comment: @ShankarSangoli $().attr('href') means it will load a blank area. If you put menu:first in the () it will load the first link when the page is refreshed

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that the fadeIn needs to occur when the load is successful. It's currently being called before the content has loaded. You need to use the load() method's callback handler argument:

```
$('.menu_side').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#main').hide().load(href, function() { $(this).fadeIn('fast'); });
  return false;
});
```

Will probably do what you want.

Comment: it still jumps to the linked file